# How to create a simple map showing the number of customers in each state

Tags: excel, google-maps, powerbi, maps, visualization

I have a table of data with two colums, `state` and `count`. The `state` column contains the names of the 50 US states. The `count` column contains the number of customers my company has in each state.

I want to dynamically generate a map that can be embedded in a website that will show, **as a number**, the number of customers in each state superimposed on top of that state.

I just want to show the actual number from the `count` column superimposed onto the map on top of the state in the `state` column. So, if California’s count is 1433, then I want to see the number 1433 superimposed on the state of California on the map, and so on for all states. **I do not need any fancy visualizations.**

I’ve tried Excel’s built-in map charts but instead of showing the count as a number, they shade each state with a color scale (darker = higher count) and you need a legend to approximate the count. I’ve tried PowerBI but they indicate the count with the size of a “bubble” being larger or smaller. I’ve tried Google Maps but I just get a single “pin” on each state that you must hover over to see the count. I don’t need anything fancy like that. In each of the above examples, you can only see the count by mousing over, hovering or clicking to see a "tooltip". I need the actual number displayed.

Note, it must be actually displayed permanently, and not “revealed” on a tooltip when you mouse over.
I’ve searched extensively and I can’t find something that is this simple. Everything I’ve tried wants to show the data with some sort of abstract visualization. **I just want to see the numbers on the map!**

Comment: Make a map.  Geocode all 50 states to get a location for the data.  Put the data on the map. Where are your running into issues?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently as close as you can get using latitude and longitude and a calculated column like the following in the location field (category labels on):

```
Country - Number = 'Table'[Country] & " - " & 'Table'[Number]
```

[image]